# Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I'm trying to run Sonaqube (9.8) on a Java (jdk 1.7) project built using maven (3.6.3). It's possible to generate the project war file using only maven, but code analisys with Sonarqube is not. When running Sonarqube's command to view the debug log, the following error is displayed.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project crt: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to download libraries from server -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project crt: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle (ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:60)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles (Jars.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download (Jars.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download (JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:60)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles (Jars.java:87)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download (Jars.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download (JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher (IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart (EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start (EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:60)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Could anyone indicate the actions to be taken to correct the problem?

Comment: To support JDK 7 you have to use an older version of SonarQube... https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/ because for [SQ 8.9](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/8.9/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/)  you need at least JDK11/17 for the scanner (sonar-maven-plugin) to run... or you use a JDK11+ and use --release option to produce Java 7 class file..... Apart from that I strongly recommend to upgrade Maven version, JDK version and SonarQube version to most recent versions etc.